# jquery slideshow center images?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

At [this URL](http://techavid.com/new-slideshow-script/final) I have modified/hack together the slideshow.  Yet the images are not centered.   I see the jquery function that powers the width in between, but do not fully understand how to get these images centered.  Might anyone have suggestions/tips?

Also the arrows disappear when they reached the last image.  How to keep them visible and make the image scroll a carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jonah ,

Something wrong your html markup , but as a quick fix...you can try this

```
.slide h2, .slide p {
    margin: 0 90px;  //top , right , bottom , left 
}
```

play around with margin , it will center it.